# Installation of ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

Im trying to install ubuntu 16.04 from cd on my amd 4 gb ram laptop.after entering the cd-rom option it just shows black screen with white dash blinking in the corner

Comment: There is no other os installed

Comment: Yep infact its dvd and i bought it from market

Comment: is it possible to do the nomodeset thing on the install? see if the answer here works for you

Comment: Its doesn't show the bios splash screen how can i do nomodoset

Comment: see if following the answer here helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu